# Load 3D objects in a specific location in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I am currently developing an augmented reality application and I want to load 3D objects during run time but it seems to me that I am having problems with loading objects.

[Screenshot of folders in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fsqE.png)

Objects should be added in the "Markerless" folder but it keeps on loading under the "Products" which is the end of all the folders. (Please see the screenshot above)

I am currently using this code in loading the object.

```
GameObject obj = (GameObject)Resources.Load ("table") as GameObject to MarkererlessEvents;
Instantiate (obj); `
```

Comment: Your link gives a "HTTP ERROR 500" error.

Answer (score 3):

The method [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) has an other constructor:

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

Which means you can define which one is the parent object in the hierarchy.

In your case it would be:

```
var parent = GameObject.Find("Markerless");
Instantiate (obj, parent.transform);
```

Your *GameObject* should now be instantiated into *Markerless* "folder".

Comment: I am getting an error Instatiate(Object, Transform) must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: Did you type it correctly ? `instatiate` -> `Instantiate` I don't have enough details to help you. What I gave you work perfectly on plain project with minimal modification.